# How do I add a UIRefreshControl to a UITableView programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to add a UIRefreshControl to a UITableView, which is in a UINavigationController. I have tried setting `tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl`, but it doesn't work properly. How can I properly add a UIRefreshControl without a storyboard?

Edit: I have narrowed it down to .prefersLargeTitles = true
Removing it fixes the problem, but I want to keep large titles

Comment: Do you want to add a custom refresh control or just the default activity indicator?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add refreshControl as below

```
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here the simple code to add `UIRefreshControl` to a `UITableView`

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

@objc func refreshData() {
 print(#function)
 // End the refreshControl after completing your task
 refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```